# C++ Operator Polymorphism

Tags: c++, oop

Consider the following C++ simple program.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

class Rectangle {
    protected:
        double width;
        double height;

    public: 
        Rectangle(double w, double h) : width(w), height(h) {};
        Rectangle operator*(double m, const Rectangle & R) {
            return Rectangle(R.width * m, R.height * m);
        }
        void display(){std::cout<<"Rect : "<<width<< ":"<<height<<std::endl;};
};

class Square : public Rectangle {
    public: 
        Square(double c) : Rectangle(c, c) {};
        Square(const Square & c) : Rectangle(c) {};
        Square(Rectangle const &other):Rectangle(other) {};
        void display(){std::cout<<"Square : "<<width<< ":"<<height<<std::endl;};
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    Rectangle r1(2, 3);
    Rectangle r2 = 2 * r1; // Working as it should

    Square c1(5);
    Square c2 = (2 * c1); // Also working
    Square c3 = (2 * r1); // But this also working :(
    
    r1.display();
    r2.display();
    c1.display();
    c2.display();
    c3.display();

    return 0; 
}
```

**Question**: Is it best to overload the operator * in Square class (i.e. write the same code twice) or to use a dedicated copy constructor as it is done in the example (but with the possibility of a Square containing a Rectangle)?

Comment: Logically, a rectangle contains a square

Comment: Sure, but lalso ogically a square cannot contain a Rectangle. So the affectation  Square c3 = (2 * r1); should not be allowed ?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him I'd say that a square _is a_ rectangle.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, bad choice of words. That is what I actually wanted to say 

Comment: Also, is friend function really necessary there?

Comment: Yes to easily access members in multiplication operator

Comment: um... why not `Rectangle operator*(const int& n) { <multiply width and height by n> }`?

Comment: might possible, but anyway it does not answer the main question ?

Comment: Frankly, yes! The function if marked public, can be used directly in the Square (overriding)

Comment: Thanks , so in your opinion, to avoid declaration of the form Square = Rectangle, I should override the code of the operator in the Sqaure class ?

Comment: A Rectangle is not a Square so the copy constructor should not be there. Try making operator*() a proper unary-operator member function `Rectangle const& operator(int)`  that returns a reference to *this, and everything should just work.

Comment: Why not eliminate the `Square` type entirely?   Just because a `Square` is a `Rectangle` with width and height equal, doesn't mean there needs to be an inheritance relationship.   An alternative is to just have `Rectangle` provide a member function `bool IsSquare() const {return w == h;}`.   Then the `operator*()` you have will be sufficient.   (Of course, testing equality of floating point values is a concern due to limited precision of floating point, but your classes are affected by that same concern simply by the fact they use `double` variables).

Comment: *to avoid declaration in the form of square = rectangle*, whatever made you think that assignment was even close to accurate? Yes, remove that assignment and make the operator* a member function. However, beware that once you do that, you'll have to use object*number and not number*object like you are, right now